# error when run dataflow example wordcount.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataflow, google-cloud-shell

I follow this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#cloud-console by using cloud shell. It is all good until this step:

And then downloaded wordcount.py from github https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py,

and try python wordcount.py --output outputs

And I receive this error, would someone please help to fix this example file?

**TypeError: Expected bytes, got unicode [while running 'Split']**

I think it is to do with this code:

```
# Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
lines = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)

counts = (
    lines
    | 'Split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn()).with_output_types(str))
    | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have ran the command on the default Cloud Shell environment which currently defaults to Python 2. The tutorial seems to require Python 3.

Try creating and entering a Python 3 virtual environment before running the command. There are instructions on doing that here: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv

Comment: Can I change the Cloud Shell environment to Python 3?